# What is the advised way to query CosmosDB using list of Ids

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

My partition Key use to be one value.  Now it's a list of users. How do I use a list for partition keys? Here is what I have for my query.

```
const string queryText = @"SELECT *
                                FROM    c
                                WHERE   ARRAY_CONTAINS(@Ids, c.UserID) = true
                                -- LastModified
                                AND DateTimeFromParts(StringToNumber(SUBSTRING(c.LastModified, 0, 4))
                                    ,StringToNumber(SUBSTRING(c.LastModified, 5, 2))
                                    ,StringToNumber(SUBSTRING(c.LastModified, 8, 2)))
                                -- Current Date/Time minus 60 days
                                    >= DateTimeAdd('day', -60, GetCurrentDateTime())
                                ORDER BY c.LastModified DESC
                                ";
        var query = new QueryDefinition(queryText);

        ids?.Add(LoggedInUser.Id);
        query.WithParameter("@Ids", ids?.ToArray());

var returnList = new List<CosmosItemModel>();
        var requestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(loggedInUserId) };
        var feedIterator = Container.GetItemQueryIterator<CosmosItemModel>(queryDefinition, null, requestOptions);
        while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            foreach (var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                returnList.Add(item);
```

But when I use LoggedInUser for mu partition key I only get documents for that user not the list of users from my query.  How can I use my list of ids for partition keys?

Comment: Not quite sure about the boolean check on `ARRAY_CONTAINS` - you don't need to do that. Just call `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` it's going to result in a true or false return value. As for partition key: if you scope your query to a single partition, then you're only going to be able to query for documents within that partition. If you want to get data for any user, you would need to perform a cross-partition query (you cannot pass a list of items for partition keys - it's a single thing - either query a single partition or do cross-partition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft advises against [querying across multiple partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-query-container#avoiding-cross-partition-queries) if you have large containers because of the RU cost.

Beyond that you can just add an `OR` to the query.

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = @partitionA OR c.partitionKey = @partitionB
```

And as David Makogon pointed out, `ARRAY_CONTAINS` probably isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Can I ask you is using Exists() instead of ARRAY_CONTAINS yield better performance and same result?

Comment: ARRAY_CONTAINS is relatively fine on performance if you are using `range` indexing as opposed to `hash`. I don't know how your data is partitioned, but generally you wouldn't have every document have its own partition. If the UserIds are related and the documents are similar, maybe they should be in the same partition with unique `id` values. Partitioning smartly is where you get the best performance and cost improvements!